# PayPal Plus as marketplace solution

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Is it possible to use PayPal Plus as marketplace solution? I have many customers, which they want to use my PayPal Plus integration for theyr payments. This meand I am renting the service and the customer of mine is setting his payment data behind the payment process.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible. I spoke with paypal and they told me, that 2017 they will bring some marketplace solution similar to paypal plus. At this moment every merchant, who wants to connect to your paypal plus account need to be approved also as separate company and paypal plus is not concepted for marketplace solution.